# Actionscript textField to BitmapData quality

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a movieclip contains text fields and i am trying to put an image of that movieclip to pdf.
i got a movieclip called page which contains 2 textfields

```
var bData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(page.width,page.height,false);
bData.draw(page);
```

and also tried drawWithQuality

```
bData drawWithQuality(page,new Matrix,null,null,null,true,StageQuality.BEST)
```

the problem is when the process is done the quality of text is really bad.
i have seen similar problem with other people but still can not find the way to fix this.
[image: that is how the output looks]

Comment: Can you put more information, hows the text appear in pdf, what code did you use to generate PDF? What you've tried so far?

Comment: i will update it, thanks

Comment: is this how it appear in PDF?

Comment: yes , that a part from the pdf file

Comment: You can debug it by adding that bitmapdata on stage, if that is correct then the issue is with your PDF code, post your PDF code

Comment: Also what size id your font? looks like 8 pixels height or similar? Are you using a Jpeg encoder for image output and what happens if you use a PNG encoder instead?

Comment: it is 10 px height, and i am using PNG encoder, i found out that it looks fine on stage and it gets bad only on pdf , it is page size problem and i am trying to figure it out now